# Mac 10.9.1 // Gerris installation //

Tags: terminal

I am trying to install Gerris . The website is :
http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation
I followed the instructions. But I could not install Gerris Dependencies.
I installed Xcode, Command line tools, Xquartz as the page suggests, but about brew not quite sure because of what terminal says for the steps below.As page says 
I make a directory.

```
% cd
% mkdir soft
```

As page says :Paths

```
For installed software to be properly localized, various environment variables have to be set accordingly in ~/.bashrc
% export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/soft/bin
% export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/X11/lib:$HOME/soft/lib
% export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig/:$HOME/soft/lib/pkgconfig
Note: make sure that the file ~/.profile contains the line
source ~/.bashrc
for these changes to be taken into account.
```

I created `nano ~/.bashrc` and included the lines:

```
    % export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/soft/bin
    % export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/X11/lib:$HOME/soft/lib
    % export
```

and pressed ctrl+X and then I created `nano ~/.profile` and include `source ~/.bashrc` on the last line and pressed ctrl+X.
But at this stage below I stuck.
    Gerris dependencies
    Now that brew is installed, almost every dependency needed by gerris can be installed in just a single command line:

```
% brew install gtkglext
% brew install gnuplot
% brew install gawk
% brew install gsl
% brew install gfortran
% brew install open-mpi
% brew install proj
% brew install netcdf
% brew install ode
% brew install fftw
% brew install ffmpeg --with-theora
% brew install coreutils
% brew install autoconf
% brew install libtool
% brew install automake
```

When I type 
    brew install gtkglext
the terminal says

```
samires-mbp:~ samirebalta$ brew install gtkglext
-bash: brew: command not found
```

I did `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` what is wrong I do not know?

Comment: Please include the actual commands you ran. We don't want to have to go check another page and you probably did not follow the instructions correctly. Your problem is that you have not installed brew but the site you linked to tells you how. If you don't tell us the commands you ran, we can't help.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com might be suitable place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are a couple of issues. First, the lines in your `.bashrc` should be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/soft/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/X11/lib:$HOME/soft/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig/:$HOME/soft/lib/pkgconfig
```

You shouldn't have the `%` at the beginning of each line, that's a mistake on the page you followed.

The other issue is that you don't seem to have installed `brew`. The page you linked to includes these instructions:

> brew
>
> Homebrew is a package manager that will make gerris (and
>   dependencies) installation smooth and manageable. To install brew,
>   just enter
>
> ```
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
> ```

So, you need to run the command above in order to install brew. Once you have done so, the `brew` command will be available and you won't get the error you show.